# asp.net c# updatepanel asyncpostback javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My javascript code below is running when the page is loaded. Updatepanel doesn't work when there is asyncpostback. I have tried many ways but without success.

HTML

```
<a onclick="direkyok()">Menü</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function direkyok() {  
          $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar mini-body"); 
  });
```

C# Page Load

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), 
                                                  "direkyok", "direkyok();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function is only defined in the scope of the parameter of `$(document).ready`. You should make it accessible for the script manager by placing it somewhere else, e.g.:

```
<script> 
    //"globally" accessible
    function direkyok() {  
          $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar mini-body"); 
    }  

    $(document).ready(/* other stuff*/);
</script>
```

Comment: Not working :(       

function direkyok() { 
          $('.navbar-mini').on('click', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar mini-navbar"); 
          });
          
      }

Comment: Why don't you test with a simple `alert('hello');`? Using an event binder only makes it more complicated and more things can go wrong.

Comment: And why do you test with another function as described in your question?